# Angular role-based routing

Tags: angular

Is there any way to implement a role-based routing in angular?

I haven't tried anything because i don't know where to start.

I have two components `LandingPageComponent` and `AdminPageComponent`. And i have basic routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './pages/landing-page/landing-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/home'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: LandingPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I also implemented JWT-based authorization and its all works just fine.
But my problem is i don't know how to implement role-based routing:

For example i have 2 roles `client` and `admin`. So when `client` visits `localhost:5000/` i want routing module to return `LandingPageComponent`, but when `admin` visits the same route routing module should return `AdminPageComponent`.

So my question is there any possibilities in angular to implement such routing module?

Comment: You should look into "Route Guards" https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. Just like an auth guard you can have a role guard. It will look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate  {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() : boolean {
    let user = localStorage.getItem(role);

    if(user !== 'admin') {
      this.router.navigate(['/user']);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And in your router:

```
{ path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard], redirectTo: 'Day', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add guard for path:

```
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    canActivate: [RoleGuard]
  }
```

In RoleGuard you can implemente canActivate method which will check user role and will navigate to correct path.